# Finding strings that begin with -- and end with a linefeed

Tags: c#, regex

I am using the following regex to locate in a document any series of characters that begins with characters dash dash `--` and ends with a line feed character `/n`.

```
return @"(^--).*?(?=\r|\n)";
```

Almost works but only when there is a space between the `--` and the next character.

```
return @"(?:--\s).*?(?=\r|\n)
```

Almost works but only when there is no space between the `--` and the next character.

***How do I get my return whether a space is following the `--` or not?***

I know nothing of regex other than what it's capable of.  I found both of these sample patterns online.  Thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `\s?` to capture either 0 or 1 spaces.

One use of the question mark in regex is to indicate that 0 or one matches of the previous character (or group of characters) will be matched, but not more than one.

Also, if you ever have the desire to learn regex for yourself, visit http://www.regular-expressions.info to learn and http://www.regexpal.com to practice.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are searching for substrings in a larger string and want to capture the the substring between `--` and `\n` you could use an expression like:

```
--(.*)\r?\n
```

Which can be quoted in C# like this:

```
@"--(.*)\r?\n"
```

If you just want to make sure that a string starts with `--` and ends with `\n` you could use:

```
(?s)^--.*\n\z
```

Comment: Does he want to capture anything, or just extra spaces at that location?

Comment: @ByteBlast, I'm assuming that he is searching for substrings in a larger string.

Comment: Plus one for your time, just tried the other answer first is all.